# Not able to fetch data from sql database in asp.net web application using vb

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am using the below code to fetch data from SQL, I am not getting any error but code is not working on button click

```
Dim strSQL As String = String.Empty
strSQL = "SELECT * from jhg"
Using connection As New SqlConnection         (ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("xyz").ConnectionString)
    Dim command As New SqlCommand(strSQL, connection)
    connection.Open()
    reader As SqlDataReader = command.ExecuteReader()
    While reader.Read()
        GridView1.DataSource = reader
    End While
'end connection and using close
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to [`DataBind`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fkx0cy6d.aspx) your GridView after providing the datasource:

`GridView1.DataBind();`

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to modify your code as follows,

```
Dim strSQL As String = String.Empty
strSQL = "SELECT * from jhg"
Using connection As New SqlConnection         (ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("xyz").ConnectionString)
    Dim command As New SqlCommand(strSQL, connection)
    connection.Open()
    reader As SqlDataReader = command.ExecuteReader()

    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt.Load(reader);
    GridView1.DataSource = dt;
    GridView1.DataBind();
```

Comment: while i am trying to use datatable it is showing me an error